# Stripping/removing the first line out of a html when importing data from an ajax query using jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In the code below, I want to edit it so that it strips out the first line.

```
function update(url,cln){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "HTML",
        error: function(msg){
            alert(msg.statusText);
            return msg;
        },
        success: function(html){
            $("#main").html(html + '<a id="MAX"></a>');
        }
    });
}
```

For example if the code contacts the url: `http://stackoverflow.com/`
The url returns:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<div id="data">
    <div id="test">
    </div>
</div>
```

It would strip out the first line so that when it writes the html to the `#main` it would only write:

```
<div id="data">
    <div id="test">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528076/delete-a-line-of-text-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches everything from the beginning of the string up to the first line break:

```
html = html.replace(/^.*?\r?\n/, '');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7pdqw/

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
^    - matches the beginning of the string
.*?  - matches zero or more character, non-greedy
\r?  - matches zero or one carriage return character
\n   - matches a line feed character
```

Comment: I put that regex into regex101 to try and work out how it works but their description isn't making any sense, eRIZ in my comments posted a link using `.splice(0,1);` which way is better, splice or a regex? Is there any advantages or disadvantages to either?

Comment: @Hyflex: I added an explanation of the regular expression above. Splitting the string up into an array and the join it back together is not an efficient way to remove part of a string. If you want to use something other than a regular expression, you should use string operations to find the line break and get the rest of the string, i.e. `html = html.substr(html.indexOf('\n'));`.

Answer (score 2):

The following will select the part of the content you need

```
function update(url,cln){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "HTML",
        error: function(msg){
            alert(msg.statusText);
            return msg;
        },
        success: function(html){
            $("#main").html($(html).find('#data').html() + '<a id="MAX"></a>');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.filter()` or `.load()`. http://api.jquery.com/load

[How do I filter the returned data from jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax)

Comment: What is the major differences over using .filter or .load over .html, all three would work wouldn't they?

Comment: @Hyflex Actually you need `.html()` AND `.find()` or `.filter()` to have the same functionality as `.load()`.